# How do I install core on Windows 10 with Nginx server?

Tags: 8, installation

I Want to install Drupal 8 on Windows 10 with nginx server.
I do know how to install with Apache using XAMPP.

I use PHP 7.2, Microsoft SQL as the db.

I installed nginx 1.18.0 and PHP in C:/

I connected them with php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000

my root file for the server is  C:/nginx/html.

I copied the extracted drupal file to the C:/nginx/html/ folder.
In the internet explorer i try to run the installation of drupal, 403 forbiden appear.

So how do I install Drupal 8 on Windows 10 with nginx server.??

my nginx configuration is:

#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

```
#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html/ltts;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html/ltts;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}
```

}

Comment: I would advise using a VM or Docker.

Comment: could you post your nginx server configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laragon https://laragon.org it's a dead-simple configuration and you can install a blank drupal 8 projects (+ tons of other options).

If you are more advanced user you can use Docker or Vagrant. I would prefer Docker-based (Lando, Docksal...)